# Onde usar acumuladores em um algoritmo de avaliação de pares e ímpares?

Tags: c, algoritmo, while, contador

Onde devo encaixar os acumuladores desse código que eu escrevi por enquanto?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

         int main()
         {

         int N;
         int somapar;
         int somaimpar;

         do{
         printf("\n Digite um número qualquer: ");
         scanf("%d", &N);

         if (N % 2 == 0){
         printf("\n Número escolhido é par!");
         }

         else {
         printf("\n Número escolhido é ímpar");
         }
         }while (N >= 0);

         printf("\n");

         return 0;
         }
```

O enunciado do algoritmo é esse:

> Escreva um algoritmo para mostrar na tela se cada número N, digitado pelo usuário é par ou ímpar. O algoritmo também deverá mostrar na tela a soma de todos os números pares, a soma de todos os números ímpares, a porcentagem de números pares e a porcentagem de números ímpares digitados. O algoritmo deverá encerrar sua execução caso o usuário digite um número menor que zero.

Comment: Se você tem outra dúvida, faça uma nova pergunta, não altere o que já foi respondido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada um deles deve ser colocado dentro do `if` afinal é nele que se decide se é par ou ímpar. Não esqueça de zerar a variável na inicialização para não pegar sujeira da memória.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N;
    int somapar = 0;
    int somaimpar = 0;
    do {
        printf("\n Digite um número qualquer: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);
        if (N % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\n Número escolhido é par!");
            somapar += N;
        } else {
            printf("\n Número escolhido é ímpar");
            somaimpar += N;
        }
    } while (N >= 0);
    printf("\nTotal de ímpares é %d e total de pares é %d\n", somaimpar, somapar);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LXr9Yv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pctgwecd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Accumulate.c).

A porcentagem e outras coisas ficam por sua conta.

Comment: amigo ainda estou com dificuldade.

Answer (score 0):

**COLOQUEI UM EXEMPLO PARA TE AJUDAR COM A MEDIA E SOMA,A PORCENTAGEM É COM VOCÊ.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // INICIALIZANDO VARIAVEIS COM 0.
    int N;
    int par = 0;
    int impar = 0;
    int somapar=0;
    int mediapar=0;
    int somaimpar=0;
    int mediaimpar = 0;

    do {
        printf("\n Digite um número qualquer: ");
        scanf("%d", &N);

        // SE O NUMERO FOR PAR ELE ENTRA AQUI
        if (N % 2 == 0) {
            printf("Número escolhido é par!\n");
            par = par + 1;
            somapar = somapar + N;
            mediapar = somapar / par;
        } 

        // SE NÃO ENTRA AQUI
        else{
            printf("\Número escolhido é ímpar!\n");
            impar = impar + 1;
            somaimpar = somaimpar + N;
            mediaimpar = somaimpar / impar;
        }
    } while (N > 0);

    // EXIBINDO RESULTADO NA TELA
    printf("------------------RESULTADO-------------------");
    printf("\nO Total de ímpares é %d e o total de pares é %d.", impar, par);
    printf("\nA soma dos numeros pares é: %d.", somapar);
    printf("\nA média dos numeros pares é: %d.", mediapar);
    printf("\nA soma dos numeros impares é: %d.", somaimpar);
    printf("\nA média dos numeros impares é: %d.", mediaimpar);
}
```

- **PARA CURIOSIDADE:** [Por que geralmente se declara uma variável com
  valor padrão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217530/por-que-geralmente-se-declara-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-com-valor-padr%C3%A3o)