# Por que geralmente se declara uma variável com valor padrão?

Tags: c#, variáveis, característica-linguagem, tipagem, declaração-de-variável

Em várias aplicações que foram escritas com linguagens fortemente tipadas, uma variável (geralmente) é declarada com seu valor padrão.

Exemplo:

```
int x = 0;
double y = 0;
```

Entretanto, é possível declará-las sem definir um valor inicial.

Desta forma:

```
int x;
double y;
```

No caso eu perguntei ao meu professor, e ele respondeu que tempos atrás, caso não fosse declarado da primeira maneira, um número absurdo seria atribuído a variável `n`, `y`.

- Essa premissa é verdadeira? Caso seja, que número é esse?
- O exemplo que demonstrei, foi baseado na linguagem C#, mas eu acredito que a declaração de variáveis, deve ser semelhante em outras linguagens. Isso também ocorre/ocorreu em outras linguagens?

Comment: É comum que as inicializem com o valor 0 para que possar somar valores dpois. Por exemplo, você quer contar quantas vezes seu programa rodou, você inicializa a variavel `count` com o valor 0 e dpois usa `count++` para cada vez que ele rodar

Comment: Dependendo da linguagem, o compilador irá tomar lugar para definir um valor a estas variáveis, ela pode ter um range aleatório muito grande, e por conta disto é necessário inicializar as variáveis. Podendo no final conter "lixo "na memória, você as inicializa para retirar este "lixo".

Comment: @Francisco Você esta levando em conta de que o autor está falando mais sobre contadores, o que no caso não é. Mas também esta certo.

Comment: Relevante para estudo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032889/2263584

Comment: Declaração <> inicialização, muitas vezes podemos não inicializar principalmente quando estamos a falar de POO's. E isso de atribuir um número absurdo acho que não é bem assim, porque senão poderia criar um vírus e esgotar todos os recurso do PC por apenas declarar variáveis

Comment: um número absurdo seria atribuído a variável, isso seria, Integer.maxvalue algo do tipo?

Comment: @Everson antigamente em certas linguagens tinha lixo de memória e realmente acontecia, hoje, principalmente em C# isso não acontece, e isso acho eu de um modo geral não tem o certo, e sim a ocasião ... depende.

Comment: @UzmkArtanis é como já houve alguns comentários, depende da linguagem em C# isso não acontece é uma premissa da linguagens, já em outras pode acontecer o lixo de memória, e a maneira correta fica a cargo de cada linguagem ... !!!

Comment: Voltaram como ampla não acredito que seja, por ter uma linguagem de referencia é fácil dizer se é fator ou não de atribuição logo na criação .

Comment: Downvoter, se você não sabe como votar pode ler aqui pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up e aqui também pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Se de tudo não souber ler, ou não quiser ler, pelo menos deixe um comentário em vez de realizar mais um downvote aleatório, explicando como posso melhorar minha resposta e contribuir com a comunidade.

Comment: Até onde sei, linguagens baseadas em C ainda tem esse comportamento de ao definir uma variável ele não limpar o endereço de memória que será utilziado para armazenar os dados da variável. Embora linguagens mais atuais já fazem isso automaticamente ainda é considerada uma boa prática de programação sempre inicializar as variáveis.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Geral

Em algumas linguagens não há inicialização, é o caso de C, aí tem que fazer manual. Em C há um acesso bruto à memória e se o programador não cuidar da inicialização pega o que estiver na memória, ou seja, sujeira, o que foi largado por aplicação que tinha aquela área reservada, ou mesmo a mesma aplicação já que há um sistema de memória virtual. Isso valia antes e vale hoje.

Não é questão de pegar um número absurdo, pode pegar exatamente o que você quer. Só que você não tem controle se deixar a linguagem fazer isso. Pode mudar a cada execução. Não sei nem se podemos dizer que é totalmente aleatório.

Em C++ também é assim. Em Assembly mais ainda. Quase para por aí. Mas C++ possui construtores e algumas variáveis sempre serão inicializadas.

Em C# não é verdade. Valia antes e vale hoje. Não existe isso de tempos atrás, existe como a tecnologia funciona.

Aproveito para deixar claro que isso tem a ver com [tipagem estática e não tipagem forte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21513/101). As pessoas confundem muito no [estilo de tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

## C#

C# é uma linguagem com memória gerenciada. Isso significa que ela não permite, até por especificação, que qualquer estado da memória esteja inválido ou com valor duvidoso. Os mecanismos específicos de como obter esse gerenciamento são especificados mais ou menos em aberto.

Todos os objetos em C# são alocados com algum valor padrão, não existe a menor chance de uma alocação de memória permitir acesso antes de todo seu dado ser inicializado. Em geral essa inicialização ocorre por um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

#### Tipos por referência

[Tipos por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) contam com duas partes, uma que estará no *heap* e será inicializado por um construtor. Mesmo que não tenha declarado um, mesmo que ele não inicialize todos os membros, o compilador inserirá código inicializado de todos eles no seu código.

Uma variável que contenha a referência, a segunda parte, será inicializado com `null` (ponteiro para 0) sempre. Não há a menor chance de ter outro valor ali, a não ser que explicitamente o seu código coloque outra coisa. Então fazer:

```
object x = null;
```

é absolutamente desnecessário. Alguns usam porque acham que fica mais legível. Eu acho que não. Eu sempre acho que qualquer informação colocada que é inambígua e que deveria ser de conhecimento do programador não ajuda na legibilidade.

Particularmente não gosto de deixar um objeto ser `null`, por mim esse conceito nem existiria na linguagem (de fato em versões recentes pode desligar isso), então eu inicializaria sempre um objeto por referência, mas se tivesse que inicializar com o `null` e na forma atual da linguagem tem caso que é útil, eu só declararia a variável deixando a inicialização implícita mesmo.

Claro que alguma operação que tente realizar posteriormente pode exigir que não seja nulo ou que o nulo seja declarado explicitamente para evitar um *bug* inesperado. Por pura facilidade do compilador ele pode informar que uma operação possivelmente resultará em erro, então ele pode exigir que seja explícito para você mostrar a ele que está ciente que o valor deve ser `null`. Mas muda nada semanticamente. Não é uma exigência para garantir o estado válido de memória.

#### Tipos por valor

[Tipos por valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) possuem alocação no mesmo local da variável e também precisam ser inicializados. A inicialização sempre é pelo valor 0 dele, ou seja todos os bits são preenchidos com 0, assim como no tipo por referência. Se não colocar valor algum é o 0 que será adotado. Então fazer:

```
int x = 0;
```

é desnecessário, a não ser por gosto.

Isso é o mesmo que fazer:

```
int x = new Int32();
```

Note que não existe valor padrão diferente de zero em qualquer objeto. O que existe é valor construído diferente de zero.

Isso não é uma coisa de primitivos da linguagem, mas alguns podem ter valores diferentes. É possível ter um construtor padrão providenciado pelo compilador. Veja:

```
DateTime x;
```

Tem valor `1/1/0001 00:00:00`, afinal se fosse tudo zerado seria uma data inválida.

O GC não poderia saber disso, não tem como ele ser responsável por isso.

Isso é feito pelo compilador. Não é que não tem inicialização, ela existe, só que é implícita. Tem os casos que é implícito no consumo, mas é explícito dentro do tipo.

Escolher ser explícito ou não, onde dá, é gosto, não muda desempenho ou semântica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/DefaultValue.cs).

## *Garbage Collector*

Nada tem a ver com o coletor de lixo, tem com o gerenciamento de memória e é garantido independente do GC. Não é o GC que faz essa inicialização. A inicialização sempre ocorrerá por construção, mesmo que seja delegado a um mecanismo do *runtime*, que não é o GC. O GC trata da alocação.

Entenda que a construção do objeto tem duas fases, a alocação, feita pelo GC e a inicialização feita por código colocado pelo compilador ou pelo [JITTer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101).

## Conclusão

Tudo isto vale para variáveis de classe ou de instância também. A pergunta não fala se são variáveis locais, mas não importa. Claro que existem pequenas diferenças entre a inicialização local, de classe e de instância.

E vale para C#, não para o [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101). A limpeza da *stack* é configurável. E no *heap* só a construção irá zerar, também depende de como o compilador emite o código.

- [Tabela de valores *default*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) - note que são todos 0, incluindo o booleano.
- [Pergunta relacionada com mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217862/101).

Comment: @bigown um exemplo bem simples a variavel g não foi inicializada ! http://ideone.com/qkQjvn ou seja, ela precisa ser inicializada com NULL

Comment: Ah, @VirgilioNovic , agora entendi o que você quiz dizer. Sim, variáveis *locais* precisam ser inicializadas via constructor ou passagem de referência - um comportamento diferente de, digamos, membros de uma classe.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim, se você fará uso que exige um `null`, é verdade, mas não que a declaração seja necessária, é que o uso posterior exige, tanto que o erro não ocorre na declaração. É uma exigência de diferente. O que está sendo falado aqui é sobre ser a declaração.Editei.

Comment: Tentar usar uma variável que não foi inicializada com um valor padrão retorna o erro `Use of unassigned local variable 'variable'` no C#. Se você define `int variable = 0` o erro some.

Answer (score 17):

Quando você cria uma variável, você está alocando um espaço reservado na memória.

O que acontece é que em algumas linguagens de programação como `C` aloca o espaço reservado na memória mas não limpa o conteúdo daquele espaço.

Exemplo: criei `int exp;` em `C`. Agora a variável existe! Mas o espaço alocado pra ela pode já ter sido usado em alguma situação. Então pode acontecer de sua variável `exp` ter um valor inteiro = 1238643485 (valor demonstrativo).

Ao criarmos uma variável da seguinte maneira `int exp = 0;` você cria a variável, e declara um valor inicial 0 que irá substituir qualquer que seja o valor antes usado naquela alocação. Dessa forma você sempre irá saber o valor exato daquela variável.

Declarar uma variável já atribuindo determinado valor ajuda no controle de contadores que usamos inúmeras vezes em nossas aplicações.

**Alocação de Memória em C#**

Mas também existem linguagens que você não terá problemas com valores já antes usados em determinada alocação, exemplo `C#`.

Isso porque existe uma determinada função chamada  **Garbage Collector (GC)** que é responsável por gerenciar e alocar a memória em sua aplicação. Você encontra um pouco mais sobre isso [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/14/09/c_garb1.htm).

Comment: Faltou dizer uma coisa sobre C# como !!! acho que iria ficar perfeito.

Comment: Falando do C# propriamente dito, a ideia de inicializar uma variável vai pra outro caminho. É impossível usar uma variável que não foi inicializada no C#. Ou seja, este deve ser o real motivo de ele ver códigos que já inicializam a variável com zero.

Comment: Quando uma aplicação em C é fechada sem limpar a memória, suas variaveis ainda ficam ocupando espaço na memória do computador?

Comment: Em C#, ao inicializar qualquer tipo primitivo ele atribui o valor padrão à variável, no caso do int é 0, assim como bool é false, etc. Se a variável for Nullable, então o valor padrão passar a ser null, no caso de uma declaração do tipo int? x;

Comment: @Francisco não ficam ocupando memória, mas os dados continuam lá até que seja escrito por cima.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática Isso não é verdade, variáveis locais **não são inicializadas**. Abra um console e faça o teste.