# Por que o compilador obriga que variáveis locais sejam inicializadas e campos não?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem

A pergunta [Por que geralmente se declara uma variável com valor padrão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217530/2541) aborda a questão da opção de inicializar ou não uma variável antes de a usar.
No entanto tal opção se torna obrigatoriedade quando se trata de uma variável local.

Um campo é inicializado automaticamente com `0`, caso seja um tipo primitivo, ou `null`, no caso de um tipo por referência.

Variáveis locais não inicializadas se forem usadas, o compilador exibe o erro:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'x'

Qual a razão dessa diferença de comportamento?

Comment: Olha, as pessoas podem responder o que for, mas no final das contas isso é assim por uma decisão de design do [Anders Rejlsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg). Ele provavelmente fez isso  para seguir o padrão do C++, mas aí a pergunta se torna por que o C++ faz isso.

Comment: É bom salientar que não é um erro, mas sim um aviso. Acho que o compilador consegue compilar,certo?

Comment: Não é um aviso. É um erro.

Comment: Depende. Se você tentar usar a variável dá erro, senão é só um aviso (de variável não utilizada).

Comment: @Renan mas é um erro, o q torna o absurdo maior

Comment: @Renan o aviso de "variável não utilizada" acontece independentemente ser local ou campo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu não poderia usar melhor [referência do que o Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30820127/221800):

- Usar `null` em um contexto local muito provavelmente é um *bug*, e nesse contexto é fácil para o compilador detectar e informar.

  Eu discordo um pouco disso. Uma notificação seria ótima, um *warning* é aceitável, mas um erro, pra mim, é algo que o compilador não deveria emitir, dentro da filosofia atual do C#. Eu até gosto disso, odeio `null`, só digo que é inconsistente. **Considero um erro do time** ter decidido que o compilador faça isso, mas é só minha opinião. Eles decidiram assim e só podemos seguir. Inclusive a resposta do Eric mostra que usam heurísticas que podem gerar resultados errados. Isso não é coisa que um compilador deveria fazer para erros e até mesmo para alertas.
- Um campo tem uma chance razoável de ser o que desejava, pelo menos temporariamente.

  Ou era no passado, hoje tem facilidades e passou não ser tão verdade assim, se aproximou um pouco da probabilidade do uso local, mas ainda tem possibilidade do `null` ser o desejado mesmo. E o compilador teria dificuldades de analisar isso pelo contexto bem mais amplo. Consideraram que não valia o esforço.

  Mas note que a linguagem não obriga nada de qualquer forma. Não tem como fazê-lo. Mesmo em especificação, é impossível. Sempre existem caminhos que tornam essa verificação indecidível, e a resposta do Eric mostra isso.

Então a decisão de colocar no compilador foi por gosto dos desenvolvedores justificando com a probabilidade de acertar aliado com a facilidade de realizar.

No final da resposta dele foi colocada as opções que tinham:

- Fazer um idioma comum, seguro e usado frequentemente ser ilegal
- Realizar uma análise muito extensiva tornando a compilação levar até mesmo horas para **tentar** descobrir um *bug* que talvez nem esteja lá
- Adotar um valor padrão e fica assim

Escolheram a última.

Minha restrição é não terem feito o mesmo com as locais.

Mas o que eu queria mesmo é que não tivesse `null`. O que eles dizem ter sido o maior erro da linguagem e que em parte resolveram em C# 8.

Não encontrei justificativa melhor para dar erro no uso da variável local não inicializada. Eu entendo perfeitamente o motivo deles, faz sentido, mas fica meio torto. Tem [mais uma resposta dele que fala algo sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013705/221800). Ali confirma que todas variáveis são inicializadas, mesmo que o `null` não seja aceito como valor válido em contexto local. [O Hans fala disso também](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013391/221800).

Note que a variável pode ser inicializada depois.

Se eles decidirem eliminar esse erro um dia não muda algo para os códigos, compila tudo existente hoje sem mudar semântica alguma. Por isso não deveria ser erro. Erro é para aquilo que nunca funciona, erro é aquilo que certamente é erro.

Para o [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) o método pode exigir inicialização ou não, lembre que o CLR roda outras linguagens, como C++ por exemplo, que não inicializa. Isso é feito com a marcação de [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) `.locals init`. Isto não faz restrição se é tipo por referência ou não. Esta marcação indica que o *stack frame* daquele método deve ser limpo, zerado, portanto, tipos por referência terão valor `null`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Concordo consigo. Resumindo, a discussão(imagino) terá sido assim: Não inicializou e usou -> quase de certeza é engano -> então vamos "dar erro" -> Ops! mas como detectar isso no caso de campos? -> Não é fácil, não, no entanto no caso de locais é simples -> OK, façamos apenas no caso de locais. Depois foram para casa convencidos de que fizeram um bom trabalho(não estou a julgar).

Comment: @ramaral exatamente isto.