# Como fazer uma função que pegue dois vetores inteiros e retorne um valor booleano?

Tags: c#, .net, declaração-de-variável

Quero fazer uma função que pegue dois vetores inteiros e que retorne um valor *boolean*, mas quando eu coloco o:

```
return (encontrou);
```

Ele fica dando erro em cima da variável `encontrou`. Segue parte da minha função:

```
public static bool verificar(int cont, int m1, int m2, int[] Cobertura1, int[] Cobertura2)
{
        bool encontrou;

        for (int i = 0; i <= cont; i++)
        {
            if ((m1 == Cobertura1[i]) & 
                (m2 == Cobertura2[i]) & 
                (m1 == Cobertura2[i]) & 
                (m2 == Cobertura1[i]))
            {
                encontrou = false;
            }
            else
                encontrou = true;
        }

        return (encontrou);
    }
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que o compilador obriga que variáveis locais sejam inicializadas e campos não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217862/18246)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro que lhe dá é por falta de inicialização da variável `encontrou`. Atribua um valor quando a declara:

```
public static bool verificar(int cont, int m1, int m2, int[] Cobertura1, int[] Cobertura2)
{
    bool encontrou = false; //agora começa a false
    ...
```

O motivo do erro é porque não existe garantia de que o `for` execute, e por isso também não existe garantia que tenha colocado `true` ou `false` na variável. E o compilador não lhe permite utilizar uma variável local, neste caso no `return`, sem que tenha atribuído um valor previamente.

Muitas das vezes da para estruturar de maneira diferente de forma a não ter este problema. No seu código está também a utilizar `&` que é o `and` binário quando devia estar a utilizar `&&` que é o `and` lógico.

Answer (score 5):

Agora entendendo a pergunta melhor, o código nem compilava e falta inicializar a variável antes de usar.

Mas tenho outras observações.

Acho que desejava usar o [`&&` e usou o `&` que em algumas situações pode produzir um resultado diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101). Algo assim:

```
public static bool verificar(int cont, int m1, int m2, int[] Cobertura1, int[] Cobertura2) {
    bool encontrou;
    for (int i = 0; i <= cont; i++) encontrou = !(m1 == Cobertura1[i] && m2 == Cobertura2[i] && m1 == Cobertura2[i] && m2 == Cobertura1[i]);
    return encontrou;
}
```

Por outro lado talvez queira isto:

```
public static bool verificar(int cont, int m1, int m2, int[] Cobertura1, int[] Cobertura2) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= cont; i++) if (!(m1 == Cobertura1[i] && m2 == Cobertura2[i] && m1 == Cobertura2[i] && m2 == Cobertura1[i])) return true;
    return false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Find.cs).

Dá para inverter a condição para eliminar o operador de negação. Nem sei se deveria ter essa negação, ou se a condição toda deveria ser esta.

O algoritmo original parece estranho, ele vai trocando estado a cada passagem diferente, acho que está funcionando por coincidência, dependendo do estado dos vetores pode dar resultado inesperado. Mas não posso afirmar sem um contexto maior.