# Arrays não inicializados

Tags: java, array

Depois da declaração

```
int[ ] a;
```

o que é armazenado na variável `a`? `null` ou um valor indefinido, onde `a` não pode ser usado até que alguma coisa se atribuído a ele?

Comment: Se for campo de objeto, é `null`. Se for variável, é indefinido e gerará um erro tentar usar `a` antes dele receber deterministicamente algum valor

Comment: Relacionado (o Java se comporta da mesmo maneira nesse aspecto): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217862/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mesmo o array sendo de tipo primitivo?

Answer (score 0):

Depende do lugar que foi realizada essa declaração. Se for um atributo o valor será null. Atributos em java recebem um valor default de inicialização. Todo atributo que o tipo é uma classe será inicializado como null. Tipos primitivos serão inicializados com um valor padrão que é definido pelo java, por exemplo, variáveis do tipo int serão inicializadas com 0.

Contudo, se essa declaração for realizada em um método, nesse caso a variável ficará em um estado de não inicializada. Se você tentar usar a variável em seguida, o compilador irá reclamar que a variável não foi inicializada.

Comment: Mas eu tenho um array [] não inicializado. Como eu posso ter null se é um array de integers?

Comment: @find83 Arrays em java também são objetos. Os elementos que você pode colocar no array que são inteiros. O array em si é um objeto. A referência para esse objeto que é nula. Uma vez instanciado o array, aí você pode adicionar inteiros nele.