# Por quê meu código não faz sentido?

Tags: c, c++, dev-c++

No meu código, tenho três "cin"s que seriam três perguntas ao usuário, para treino dos ifs. No caso, ao final temos

```
if((cadastro == 1) && ((ativo == 1) || (logado == 1))){
    printf("Tudo certo!\n\n");
} else {
    printf("Algo deu errado.\n\n");
}
```

Ou seja, se a variável cadastro for um `1`, e uma das outras duas variáveis ao lado, forem 1, eu teria a resposta "Tudo Certo", certo?
Pois de acordo com a tabela verdade do `||`, basta um dos dois ser verdadeiro, para então a resposta ser verdadeira, certo?
Mas ao executar e dar a resposta `S`, `N` e `N`, eu obtenho a resposta "Tudo certo", alguém sabe me explicar o motivo disso?

Código completo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){

int cadastro, ativo, logado;
char opcao;

cadastro, ativo, logado=0;



printf("Deseja cadastrar sua conta? S/N\n\n");
scanf(" %c", &opcao);

if((opcao == 'S') || (opcao == 's')){
    printf("Conta cadastrada.\n\n");
    cadastro = 1;
}

printf("Deseja ativar sua conta? S/N\n\n");
scanf(" %c", &opcao);

if((opcao == 'S') || (opcao == 's')){
    printf("Conta ativada.\n\n");
    ativo = 1;
}

printf("Deseja logar sua conta? S/N\n\n");
scanf(" %c", &opcao);

if((opcao == 's') || (opcao =='S')){
    printf("Conta logada.\n\n");
    logado = 1;
}

if((cadastro == 1) && ((ativo == 1) || (logado == 1))){
    printf("Tudo certo!\n\n");
} else {
    printf("Algo deu errado.\n\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você não inicializou as variáveis `cadastro` e `ativo` com 0. Pode ser que elas estejam com o valor 1 porque ela ficou com o valor que já estava na memória do seu computador.

Comment: **Apenas ZERO é falso**. Qualquer outro valor é verdadeiro. Não apenas 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sua ideia for inicializar as variáveis **cadastro**, **ativo** e **logado** em **0** então troque `cadastro, ativo, logado=0;`por `cadastro = ativo = logado = 0;`

de uma olhada neste tópico sobre [inicialização de variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217530/por-que-geralmente-se-declara-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-com-valor-padr%C3%A3o)

Em relação a condicional que não esta retornando o resultado esperado...

```
if((cadastro == 1) && ((ativo == 1) || (logado == 1))){
    printf("Tudo certo!\n\n");
} else {
    printf("Algo deu errado.\n\n");
}
```

Seguindo a ordem de precedência primeiro é avaliado os parênteses mais internos
`(cadastro == 1) && ((ativo == 1)` que são False por que a está altura as variáveis **cadastro** e **ativo** vão ser 1 e 0 e pela tabela verdade 1 e 0 = False e a variável **logado** também estará em 0 ou seja...

```
[(True && False) || False] = False
```

Segue abaixo os código com uns printf entre as condições para você acompanhar as variáveis em tempo de execução.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){

int cadastro, ativo, logado;
char opcao;

cadastro = ativo = logado = 0;


printf("\n===%i %i %i\n===", cadastro, ativo, logado);

printf("Deseja cadastrar sua conta? S/N\n\n");
scanf(" %c", &opcao);

if((opcao == 'S') || (opcao == 's')){
    printf("Conta cadastrada.\n\n");
    cadastro = 1;
}

printf("\n===%i %i %i\n===", cadastro, ativo, logado);

printf("Deseja ativar sua conta? S/N\n\n");
scanf(" %c", &opcao);

if((opcao == 'S') || (opcao == 's')){
    printf("Conta ativada.\n\n");
    ativo = 1;
}

printf("\n===%i %i %i\n===", cadastro, ativo, logado);

printf("Deseja logar sua conta? S/N\n\n");
scanf(" %c", &opcao);

if((opcao == 's') || (opcao =='S')){
    printf("Conta logada.\n\n");
    logado = 1;
}

printf("\n===%i %i %i\n===", cadastro, ativo, logado);

if((cadastro == 1) && ((ativo == 1) || (logado == 1))){
    printf("Tudo certo!\n\n");
} else {
    printf("Algo deu errado.\n\n");
}

printf("\n===%i %i %i\n===", cadastro, ativo, logado);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Os parênteses mais internos são o `(ativo == 1) || (logado == 1)`.